# "Высшее Я": нужны ли кавычки?

Tags: орфография

И, кстати, еще о сакральном)) В таком выражении, как "Высшее Я", как, собственно, пишется "Я"? С большой буквы или с маленькой? В кавычках или без? В тексте было написано с большой буквы и без кавычек.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотря что Вы имеете в виду.Если философию буддизма, к ней чаще восходят в сакральных текстах, то верно именно "Высшее Я" как термин, означающий "Бог внутри","Сверхсознание".   Если просто о  развитии личности, рекомендуется писать тоже с большой буквы, т.к. личность – это практически самое ценное, что существует в человеке. Иногда Я -это символ просто индивидуальности, тогда говорят:  важно различать низшее я, или эго, и высшее Я. В этом случае можно Я взять в кавычки, чтобы сконцентрировать внимание на значении слова "индивидуальность" в отличие от личности - носителя высоких качеств.

Comment: Вы сознательно противопоставили строчную в "низшем я" и заглавную в "высшем Я"

Comment: Да, сознательно, подчёркивая нравственную высоту понятия.По правилам русского языка с прописной буквы пишутся слова в особом стилистическом употреблении - Родина, Отчизна, Человек и др. К этому же здесь относится и Я - как нечто высокое в личности, если речь идёт о "высшем Я".Это выражение уважения к себе как и Вы - уважение к личности того, к кому обращаешься.